# Mathematical definition of QUBO problem

Tags: optimization, annealing, qubo

The quantum annealing approach is using the equivalence between QUBO matrix and Ising Hamiltonian to solve the problem. Therefore, it is necessary to transform a NP-hard problem into a QUBO matrix. However, I still don't figure out the mathematical definition of QUBO matrix. Does it mean that we transfer a target function f (which reflects the original NP-hard) problem to a quadratic function at first? The solution of function f is binary encoded (either 1 or 0). But what does unconstrained mean? As far as I understood, unconstrained means that the value of each variable could be any possible value, correct? If variables are binary encoded then why do they should be unconstrained here (since unconstrained means they can be 2,3 and so on)? Can anyone explain this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Unconstrained means that there are no additional requirements on relations among variables, for example $\sum x_i =1$. We only want the variables to be either 0 or 1.

Comment: @MartinVesely Thank you for your answer. Can you explain what does relations among variables mean? Thank you.

Comment: This was only an example. In this particular case the relation means that only one of some variables can be equal 1.